# How can I make arbitrary shadows on vector like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

So as the title says, how can i make arbitrary shadows on vector like this without some colored vector on which that shadow will be put?

Comment: --- What have you tried? ---

Comment: What do you mean with "arbitrary"? It doesn't look like the shadow was randomly added to the image. Plus there is an object there, with the same color as the background.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a radial gradient for this. In the example below I created a radial gradient and squished it a little to make it oval shaped.

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is a cool method, I would set the inner color to 0% opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Billy Kerr suggested a good idea, I'm going to expand on it.

I created a radial gradient with two colors:

White, Opactiy 0%, Location 0%
Black, Opacity **30%**, Location 100%

Adjust the bold value depending on how dark you want the shadow.

Adjust the slider depending on how large you want the shadow.

---

This allows for the shadow to be drawn on almost any color background.

[image: GIF showing shadow on various backgrounds]

Comment: actually I'd make the inner color black 0% instead of white, you can see a weird white-ish halo in some of the background colors

Comment: @Luciano true, I guess that color can have varying degree of blackness-whiteness depending on use case.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the **Mesh Tool** to make a mesh around the areas you want the color
  get darker
- Use the **Lasso Tool** to select areas to change the color
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** move the mesh points

[image]

Read more about how to work with a mesh [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/meshes.html)

Comment: Naah i think its a gaussian blur with some extra stuff on top

Comment: Could be, I think there are several ways to get it

Comment: Yeah but its very very close by default (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoHc0.png)), you'd be using a gradient mesh for a long time for same effect.